# Optimizing group by query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I think the solution for my problem shouldn't be difficult but I'm getting an headache now as I can't find the solution myself.

For a webshop, I'm trying to create a simple query which selects the lowest and highest price of all products in a specific category. Now, the issue, I'm having right now is that almost all products have different types (lets say 40 inch tv, 42 inch tv, 46 inch). What I'd like to do now is to only use lowest price for each product_id when I'm trying to get the lowest and maximum price of all products. I have managed to do that, however, the query is way too slow because of the Group By clause. It takes about 40 seconds to load the query. Any ideas how to optimize this query?

```
SELECT MIN(product_price), MAX(product_price)
FROM products_inventory
WHERE inventory_id IN (
    SELECT pi.inventory_id 
    FROM products_inventory  pi
    JOIN products p ON p.product_id = pi.product_id
    JOIN category_products cp ON cp.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE cp.category_id IN (4,5,6,118)
    GROUP BY product_id
    ORDER BY product_price
)
```

An example of how the tables look like:

```
products: product_id, product_name
products_inventory: inventory_id, product_id, product_price
category_products: category_id, product_id
```

As asked, here is some sample data:

```
products:
1, lg tv
2, samsung tv

products_inventory
1, 1, 500
2, 1, 750
3, 1, 800
4, 2, 450
5, 2, 600

category_products
1, 1
1, 2
```

Based on the sample data the output of the query should be:
450 - 500

Comment: Have you indexed the fields included in the WHERE clause?

Comment: IN with SELECT is really bad idea.... it's like ORing hundreds or million values....

Comment: Yes, the fields in the where clause are all indexed

Comment: @Shiraz can you able to add some sample records in this tables

Comment: @AshishJagtap I have added some sample data :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, first of all I do not see any difference between your query and the one below:

```
SELECT MIN(product_price), MAX(product_price)
FROM products_inventory  pi
JOIN products p ON p.product_id = pi.product_id
JOIN category_products cp ON cp.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id IN (4,5,6,118)
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_price
```

This should work in the totally same way and be more performant because you avoid useless operation.

Well, now let's increase the performance (and you say the problem is in group by clause).

Let's trust you and increase the performance by adding covering index:

```
create index my_covering_index on products_inventory(product_id,product_price);
```

The important point in this kind of indices is to use everything from "where" clause, then from "group by" clause and then from "select" clause.

Usually this should be enough to enhance your query with a Honda motor :)

Comment: Also should have a covering index on the category_products table on (product_id, category_id)

Comment: not sure, because it is not used in group by clause and usually category is a small table, which usually means it will avoid usage of index because it is slower than scanning of the full table. At least in Oracle this would be like that. If it is a big table then, of couse, index would be useful

Comment: again there is a contra: all the value-pairs are unique, I guess, and index is mostly useless then.

Comment: You don't have to group at all. Why order as well? How should it order when it has no product_price column but MIN and MAX? Those quirks work only because mysql allows it, unfortunately it teaches but SQL habits...

Answer (score 1):

It's not grouping slowing you down, but IN clause... what happens when you use IN is the same as you would OR each result row... which is veeery slow.

You have to join it, which is much faster:

```
SELECT MIN(pi.product_price), MAX(pi.product_price)
FROM products_inventory pi
    JOIN products p ON p.product_id = pi.product_id
    JOIN category_products cp ON cp.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id IN (4,5,6,118)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're query is fast but it gives the lowest and highest price for each product_id. What I'm trying to achieve is the lowest and highest price for all products so the result should be one row.

Comment: @Rafal Ziolkowski this query is right please check my sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Rafal Ziolkowski is correct please check the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be1cc/1) for your sample data and query result.

hope this will solve your problem !

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I made a mistake in my post. The output should be 450-500 instead of 450-800. The maximum value should be the maximum value of the lowest value of all products